# Php 5.3 upgrade at Debian lenny

Tags: php, apache

How can I upgrade php to 5.3 version at Debian lenny from squeeze packages?
Will Zend Optimezer and ionCube work with php 5.3?

Answer (score 0):

I know Zend Optimizer does not work with 5.3, tried it recently.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I upgrade php to 5.3 version at Debian lenny from squeeze packages

You shouldn't do that because squeeze's version has dependencies that do not exist in Debian lenny until to the C library.

You should download squeeze's source package and build your binary package from that instead.

Zend optimizer does not support PHP 5.3 yet, but you can use other opcode caches such as [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/apc) instead.